# Define new CSS color name

Tags: css, sass, less

We know the HTML standard defines a bunch of colors, but can I define and use new color in less css?

Say I want to have a color DoctorWhite, and I want to use it like

`background-color:DoctorWhite;`

I know less css can define variables and use it with the at(@) notation. But it doesn't look like a native color.

Is it achivable in less css? Or does any other CSS pre-processor support this?

Comment: What if somebody else adopts your code-base, and is mistakenly led to believe your "DoctorWhite" is a real color, and tries to use it elsewhere. Isn't it best to use a variable for variables, for the sake of clarity and maintainability? If you really wanted to do this, you could use something like PostCSS to find/replace these values.

Comment: @Sampson I'm talking about technical feasibility.

Comment: LoveRight, then yes, it's possible. Tools like PostCSS could accomplish this as part of your build-process. But again, please don't do it; for your own sake, and the sake of others :) Generally speaking, you should try to stick with non-named colors anyway.

Comment: @LoveRight You could use CSS Variables, but they are not supported by all browsers. Support [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables), Demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/owv5q7sk/).

Comment: Defining new colors like this makes complete sense for my neural network.

Comment: In less I think is not possible but in [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) you can define variables without any symbols: `DoctorWhite=#ffffee`

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using [CSS custom properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)?

```css
:root {
  --stackoverflow: #f69c55;
}
.rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.rectangle.default-color {
  background-color: black;
}
.rectangle.custom-color {
  background-color: var(--stackoverflow);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle default-color">
  <!-- will become black -->
</div>
<div class="rectangle custom-color">
  <!-- will become orange -->
</div>
```

Here, the [`var()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#funcdef-var) function is used to set the value of the `background-color` property of `.rectangle.custom-color` to the value of the `--stackoverflow` variable (i.e. `#f69c55`).

Bear in mind that this is a W3C Candidate Recommendation (intended to become a W3C spec), so as @Ricky_Ruiz suggested, make sure it is supported by the browsers you are targeting using a service like [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

Side note: The two dashes (`--`) at the beginning of the custom variable name are not arbitrary:

> A custom property is any property whose name starts with two dashes (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), like `--foo`. The  production corresponds to this: it’s defined as any valid identifier that starts with two dashes.

Have a look at [section 2 of the Candidate Recommendation document](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#defining-variables) for more.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In LESS, like you said, variables are marked with an `@`. In Sass, they are marked with a `$`. Examples if your DoctorWhite was `#fffffe`:

**LESS:** `@DoctorWhite: #fffffe; div {background-color: @DoctorWhite}`
**Sass:** `$DoctorWhite: #fffffe; div {background-color: $DoctorWhite}`

As **@blonfu** says, in Stylus they aren't marked with anything - so if your objective is to make anyone who sees your pre-preprocessored stylesheets think your custom color name is a standardized color name, that might work. (But it's hard to imagine the use case…)

**Stylus:**

```
DoctorWhite = #fffffe

put a bunch of other styles here so the viewer doesn't notice you defined DoctorWhite

div
  background-color DoctorWhite
```

But in all cases, you aren't actually defining a new color name in the sense that HTML has a color `WhiteSmoke`. The compiled CSS (as it appears in the loaded stylesheet, and as it will appear in a browser's inspector) will still use the hex value you gave `DoctorWhite` — in all of the above examples, or if you do a custom CSS property solution, the CSS will be
`div {background-color: #fffffe}`.